# how to set the rotate axis?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I import two links from solidworks, they are stl files, and I add coodinate system on a hole of the two links,now I want to make the second lind rotate around the setted X axis, but it can not ,how can I deal with it? the code as follow:
link:
0 1.0 0.0 0 0 0


.......link1.stl

world
        link
        
          1 0 0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/353/how-to-set-the-rotate-axis?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-03**:
Can you clarify? I cant quite tell what you're asking.

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2012-12-03**:
I will use plugin animate a link rotate around a setting axis of a coordinate system attached on another link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but I'll go by what I think you're asking.

The coordinate system transformations are based on the joints only. That is to say that the link transformations have no effect on where the next joint is placed, so your stl files and where you set their origins to are irrelevant.

Therefore you must place the next joint with respect to the previous one. In the code you pasted you do not set an origin, so it will likely default to 0, 0, 0 which would put it exactly on top of the last one.

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2012-12-04**:
thank you!